# Best and common practices for config dependent behaviours

Tags: design-patterns, configuration, architecture, settings

I'm dealing with a large industrial scale system. It has hundreds of configuration settings with multiple overlapping combinations.

ex. Method: SendMessage(MessageObject)
Settings: MessageType (1,2,3,4)

Message type changes the behavior of sendMessage:
I usually encounter code like this:

```
sendMessage(MessageObject)
{
  switch(messageType)
  case 1: code for Behaviour1
  case 2: code for Behaviour1 + some other behavior
  case 3: code for Behaviour3
  case 4: code for case 2 + some other behaviour
  ...
}
```

So when I clean it up, I did this.

```
sendMessage(MessageObject)
{
  switch(messageType)
  case 1: sendMessageType1();
  case 2: sendMessageType2();
  case 3: sendMessageType3();
  case 4: sendMessageType4();
  ...
}
```

This is my attempt to decouple the code and make it maintainable. This also means duplication, redundancies and for every new setting, a new method should be declared.

Is this an acceptable approach? What is the best approaches to implement these settings? Is there like a software architecture or design pattern that solves this?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using `switch` statement with following approach, which may seem over engineering.

```
public interface IMessageSender
{
    int MessageType { get; }

    void Send();
}

public class TypeOneMessageSender : IMessageSender
{
    public int MessageType => 1;
    public void Send()
    {
        //logic here for sending 1 type of message
    }
}

public class TypeTwoMessageSender : IMessageSender
{
    public int MessageType => 2;
    public void Send()
    {
        //logic here for sending 2 type of message
    }
}

public class MessageSender
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<IMessageSender> _senders;

    /*inject IReadOnlyList<IMessageSender> with DI*/
    public MessageSender(IReadOnlyList<IMessageSender> senders)
    {
        _senders = senders;
    }

    public void Send(int messageType)
    {
        var sender = _senders.FirstOrDefault(it => it.MessageType == messageType);
        if(sender == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to send message of type {messageType}")  ;
        sender.Send();
    }
}
```